# Node http-proxy in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker, node-http-proxy

I have the following code that works great in my local environment. However, when I try to run the same code from a Docker container (via Boot2Docker), I simply cannot get to https://[boot2docker_ip]:4000

I tried updating the target value in the code below with all these options but none of them seemed to do the trick:

`target: 'http://localhost:3000',`
`target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',`
`target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',`
`target: 'http://<boot2docker_ip>:3000',`

```
var fs = require('fs');    

require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/ssl.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/ssl.crt', 'utf8')
  },
  target: 'http://localhost:3000',
  ws: true,
  xfwd: true
}).listen(4000);
```

I am using the `node-http-proxy` package from https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

### Edit

Here is a [Git repo](https://github.com/munjalpatel/node-http-proxy-test) to try out this behavior; I have checked in fake SSL for simplicity.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM readytalk/nodejs

ADD ./src /app
ADD ./ssl-proxy /proxy

COPY ./run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

**run.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

/nodejs/bin/node /app/main.js; /nodejs/bin/node /proxy/main.js
```

Comment: Where is the service that's listening on port 3000 running? On your host machine, or inside another Docker container?

Comment: Inside the same docker container. I start this proxy first and then that service on port 3000

Comment: I see. Your Dockerfile and/or the `docker run` command that you're using to start the container might be useful.

Comment: Check to edit. Here is the repo for you to try out: https://github.com/munjalpatel/node-http-proxy-test

Comment: Alright! I edited your question to include the code in question (typically, link-only questions and answers are discouraged on SO because links tend to become invalid) and drew up an answer below. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had a look at your Dockerfile and especially the `run.sh` script that you use. This line is from your `run.sh` script:

```
/nodejs/bin/node /app/main.js; /nodejs/bin/node /proxy/main.js
```

What's important to know here is that each of these commands start a long-running server process that (theoretically) runs forever. This means that the second process (`/proxy/main.js`) will never start because the shell will wait for the first process to finish.

This means that **you cannot access your proxy server because it never starts**.

Basically there are two solutions to this that I could think of. Please note that the idiomatic "Docker way" is to run **one process per container only**, though.

1. I'd recommend running your application and the proxy server in **two separate containers**. You can [link those two containers together](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/):

   ```
   docker run --name app -p 3000 <your-image> /nodejs/bin/node /app/main.js
   docker run --name proxy -l app:app -p 4000:4000 <your-image> /nodejs/bin/node /proxy/main.js
   ```

   The flag `-l app:app` will cause the `app` container to be available with the hostname `app` in your `proxy` container (this is done by creating a `/etc/hosts` entry in the container). This means, inside the proxy container, you can then use `http://app:3000` to access your upstream application port.
2. An alternative solution would be to use a **process manager tool** like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage several long-running processes in your container in parallel. There's a [good article](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) on that in the documentation. It basically boils down to the following:

   1. Install supervisord (`apt-get install supervisor` in Ubuntu)
   2. Create a configuration file (typically in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/yourapplication.conf`) in which you configure all services that you need to run:

      ```
      [supervisord]
      nodaemon=true

      [program:application]
      command=/nodejs/bin/node /app/main.js

      [program:proxy]
      command=/nodejs/bin/node /proxy/main.js
      ```
   3. Then use `supervisord` as your start command, for example by using `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]` in your Dockerfile.

   In this case, both your processes are running in the same container and you can use `http://localhost:3000` to access your upstream application.